# Possibility CSS3 Border similar to image

Tags: css

I'm interest to know if it's possible to create a border with css3 which is similar to the following image?

[image]

Comment: The image is not very clear on what exactly is that *border effect*. It would be better if you can describe the effect. While not mandatory, it would also be good if you can show us your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-shadow`

```css
body {
  background: grey
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #666;

/* BOX SHADOW APPLIES THE EFFECT YOU'RE AFTER */
  box-shadow: inset 0 -18px  16px -16px #444, 0 6px  6px -7px #fff, 0 14px  8px -7px #444;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```